# Writing same line different text for xslt

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0, text-align

I need to write text same line left and right side together but after right side start next line from previous line to the left.

Please help for this.

[image]

Note: I copied just needed places. maybe syntax problem for that.

```css
<div margin-top="14px" border-top="1px solid #DDD" overflow="hidden" padding-top="8px" padding-bottom="2px" content="">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="blackBorder" style="width:100%">
<!--    <table style="width:100%">-->
      <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
          <td> 
        <table border="0" style="float:right"
             margin-left="8px" width='30%' > 

              <xsl:for-each select="//n1:Invoice/cbc:Note">
                 <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(.,0,10)='NOT:BANKA'">
                        <th font-weight="normal" text-align="left" tr="first-child" border-bottom="1px solid red" colspan="2">
                          <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,5)"/>
                         </th>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//n1:Invoice/cac:PaymentMeans">
                          <xsl:if test="cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:CurrencyCode = 'TRY'">
                            <xsl:if test="cbc:PaymentMeansCode != 'ZZZ'">
                              <tr>
                                <th>
                                  <xsl:value-of select="cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:PaymentNote"/>
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                  <xsl:value-of select="cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:ID"/>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </xsl:if>
                          </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
     </table>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
          <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="//n1:Invoice/cbc:Note">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(.,0,5)='NOT:'">
                      <tr align="left" valign="top">
                        <td align="left" style="padding:2px 0px">
                          <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,5)"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(.,0,13) = ':NOT-AYIRAC:'">
                      <tr align="left" valign="top">
                        <td align="left" style="padding:2px 0px">
                          <hr/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </xsl:when>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: First find a stable and clear and working static HTML layout that gives you the alignment and layout you expect. Then start thinking about creating that layout with XSLT.

Comment: Edit your question so that it concerns only HTML. It's not an XSLT issue.